# Issue with GPB SerializeTo functions

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I have the below code.

```
main()
{
    test::RouteMessage *Rtmesg = new test::RouteMessage;
    test::RouteV4Prefix *prefix = new test::RouteV4Prefix;
    test::RouteMessage testRtmesg;

    prefix->set_family(test::RouteV4Prefix::RT_AFI_V4);
    prefix->set_prefix_len(24);
    prefix->set_prefix(1000);

    Rtmesg->set_routetype(test::RouteMessage::RT_TYPE_BGP);
    Rtmesg->set_allocated_v4prefix(prefix);
    Rtmesg->set_flags(test::RouteMessage::RT_FLGS_NONE);
    Rtmesg->set_routeevnt(test::RouteMessage::BGP_EVNT_V4_RT_ADD);
    Rtmesg->set_nexthop(100);
    Rtmesg->set_ifindex(200); Rtmesg->set_metric(99);
    Rtmesg->set_pref(1);
    int size = Rtmesg->ByteSize();

    char const *rt_msg = (char *)malloc(size);

    google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream oarr(rt_msg, size);
    google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream output (&oarr)

    Rtmesg->SerializeToCodedStream(&output);


    // Below code is just to see if everything is fine.
    google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputtStream iarr(rt_msg, size);
    google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream Input (&iarr)

    testRtmesg.ParseFromCodedStream(&Input);

    Vpe::RouteV4Prefix test_v4Prefix = testRtmesg.v4prefix();
    cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Family " << test_v4Prefix.family() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Prefix " << test_v4Prefix.prefix()<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "PrefixLen " << test_v4Prefix.prefix_len() << std::endl;

    // All the above outputs are fine.

    cout << std::endl;
    cout << rt_msg; <<------------ This prints absolutely junk.
    cout << std::endl;

    amqp_bytes_t str2; 
    str2 = amqp_cstring_bytes(rt_msg);  <<----- This just crashes.
    printf("\n str2=%s %d", str2.bytes, str2.len);
```

}

Any operation on the above rt_msg just crashes. I want to use the above buffer to send to socket and another rabbitmq publish APIs.

Anybody out there who had similar issue...or worked out similar code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocol Buffers is a binary serialization format, not text.  This means:

- Yes, if you write the binary data to cout, it will look like junk (or crash).
- The data is not NUL-terminated like C strings.  Therefore, you cannot pass it into a function like `amqp_cstring_bytes` which expects a NUL-terminated `char*` -- it may cut the data short at the first 0 byte, or it may search for a 0 byte past the end of the buffer and crash.  In general, any function that takes a `char*` but does not also take a length won't work.

I'm not familiar with `amqp`, but it looks like the function you are trying to call, `amqp_cstring_bytes`, just builds a `amqp_bytes_t`, which is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct amqp_bytes_t_ {
  size_t len;
  void *bytes;
} amqp_bytes_t;
```

So, all you have to do is something like:

```
amqp_bytes_t str2;
str2.bytes = rt_msg;
str2.len = size;
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that and fixed it. Its good to know that from you again.